# AWS-Linux-Docker-Selenium grid Cannot start service chrome: port is already allocated error

Tags: linux, docker, selenium, docker-compose, selenium-grid

I am using AWS-Linux-Docker-Selenium grid configuration to run selenium tests. `docker-compose up` is running fine and I am able to see single containers for chrome,firefox,opera.

```
docker-compose up
```

[image: docker-compose up]

But when I try to create container nodes using `docker-compose scale chrome=3` I am getting below error. I have tried so many ways likes changing Linux instance, `sudo service docker restart`  I am not getting away with this. Please help how to scale up chrome containers.

```
 docker-compose scale chrome=3
```

[image]

```
 Cannot start service chrome: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint ec2-user_chrome_3 (f0d153ee59169eaf94501b8dc9e77db4157614afd731cba673f2aed6c054d237): Bind for 0.0.0.0:6900 failed: port is already allocated
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
# To execute this docker-compose yml file use `docker-compose -f docker-compose-v3.yml up`
# Add the `-d` flag at the end for detached execution
# To stop the execution, hit Ctrl+C, and then `docker-compose -f docker-compose-v3.yml down`
version: "3"
services:
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:4.0.0-beta-1-prerelease-20210114
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
    ports:
      - "6900:5900"

  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox:4.0.0-beta-1-prerelease-20210114
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
    ports:
      - "6901:5900"

  opera:
    image: selenium/node-opera:4.0.0-beta-1-prerelease-20210114
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
    ports:
      - "6902:5900"

  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:4.0.0-beta-1-prerelease-20210114
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4442:4442"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "4444:4444"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your node is configured to expose VNC port to a certain port of host and when you start several nodes they all try to bind on that port.

Instead of:

```yaml
    ports:
      - "6901:5900"
```

You need to use:

```yaml
    ports:
      - "5900"
```

This will make your docker compose to expose container port to a randomly chosen free port of your host.

Comment: You are awesome Alexey. You just easily solved my issue which I was struggling for hours. I am new to this docker, container orchestration concepts. Can you please share any links for the tricks, docs, tutorials. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm afraid there is no single point of knowledge. Regarding the compose tool, you may find the complete specification [here](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md).